# what happened to Disasm?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

Anyone knows what happened to Go Ethereum Disasm (disassembler) ?

The repo used to be here: https://github.com/eris-ltd/go-ethereum/cmd/disasm
and apparently the latest version available was 1.3.3 on Jan 2016.

In recent ethereum documentations it mentions that it is included in the packages

> For all archives we provide separate ones containing only Geth, and separate ones containing Geth along with all the developer tools from our repository (abigen, bootnode, disasm, evm, rlpdump). Please see our README for more information about these executables.
>
> To download these bundles, please head the Go Ethereum Downloads page.
>
> source: https://geth.ethereum.org/install/

However after installing the package (e.g `Geth & Tools 1.5.8`) it only includes these fils:

> COPYING
> abigen
> evm
> geth
> rlpdump
> swarm

anyone with a linux or Mac os x link would save me

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the source file to compile disasm:

> go get github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/disasm