# How to install geth disasm and other dev tools

Tags: go-ethereum, evm

The geth disassembler seems like a really nice tool, if it can do stuff like this:

```
To disassemble, run echo 6005600401 | disasm, which produces:

0      PUSH1  => 05
2      PUSH1  => 04
4      ADD
```

However I couldn't find it, tried the solution [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/what-happened-to-disasm/11883), and ran into this error:

[image]

How can we install the dev tools such as `disasm`?

Comment: Not the same but I've found this helpful https://github.com/Arachnid/evmdis.

Comment: Yes, what @Ismael suggests may well be easier than what I've put in my (updated) answer. The official documentation looks a bit sketchy with regards to what's happened with the tools package...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the "Geth & Tools 1.7.0" package from the official [Downloads](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) page. You should be able to just unzip the package and run the binaries directly.

However, it should be noted that the `disasm` tool no longer exists by itself - it was integrated with the main `evm` tool in commit [#3729](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/3729). Meaning you'll have to run the `evm` tool and pass the `disasm` flag as an argument.

---

The other option is to compile the tool yourself using the `disasm.go` file, and whatever other Go packages are required. This is the approach used in the previous answer you've linked to, but you'll need to understand how to pull everything together for the compilation. The main file has changed locations to the following:

```
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/evm/disasm.go
```

Comment: so I found it in `/Users/s.matthew.english/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/evm/disasm.go`, but when I ran the command `./disasm.go`, I got the error `zsh: permission denied: ./disasm.go` and then `sudo: ./disasm.go: command not found`

Comment: Hi there. That's just the Go source file - you'd need to compile it to get it to work. (That's what the user in the other question seems to have done.) I've had more of a poke around, and found that the `disasm` tool no longer exists as a standalone tool like it did before. I've updated my answer...

Answer (score 1):

It's been subsumed by the `evm` tool, but you can call it like this (*for example*):

```
echo "6005600401" >> tst && evm disasm tst   
6005600401
000000: PUSH1 0x05
000002: PUSH1 0x04
000004: ADD
```